# Thread.sleep() in Multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have question regarding Thread.sleep() in the use of multi-threading. If multi-threading allows concurrent execution then what is the purpose of Thread.sleep(). From what I know, Thread.sleep() suspends the current thread for a period of time and allow other threads to execute. However, if multi-threading allows multiple threads to run concurrently why would Thread.sleep() be used? I am asking this because I have seen a lot of example codes with the use of Thread.sleep() in multi-threading program.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is mostly used for "sample code" or demonstration purposes, but sometimes you also need it in a "real application"...when a thread is "too fast"! :) ...or "wants to" get "interrupted", but therefor maybe really better approaches.

Comment: Concurrently **DOES NOT MEAN** at the same time. IN PARALLEL means at the same time. So, just to make it blatantly clear **`CONCURRENCY ≠ PARALLELISM`**

Comment: sleep is mostly used to avoid busy waiting, when you wait for some resource or event and definitely know that it won't happen during next x milliseconds. Though, there are better techniques

Comment: You can write two emails concurrently (you can start the second before sending the first); but you can't write them in parallel (typing the contents of both simultaneously).

Comment: in multi-threading, you cant be sure how JVM will schedule each thread.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to give other threads a chance to execute, there's nothing you have to do for it, it happens automatically.

You call `Thread.sleep()` if you want your thread to just do nothing for a given amount of time, maybe because you want some specific timing behaviour, maybe you want to wait some time before you check for some condition (e.g. new data arrived) the next time. [There are other possibilities to do that, e.g. the `Timer` class.]

A side-effect of `Thread.sleep()` is that one thread less competes for the CPU, so the other threads can get a bigger share of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question:

> From what I know, Thread.sleep() suspends the current thread for a period of time and allow other threads to execute

I guess the misunderstanding comes from the part which you state "it allows other thread to execute". While it's true that Thread.sleep() suspends the current thread, it does not mean it allows other thread to execute.
An app might have more than 1 Thread, let's say Thread A and B, and you decided to call Thread.sleep() in thread A. Is thread B "allowed to execute"? No, it has been running from the beginning.